# How to get data with React from array in state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React.
I have an array in my state and I have a function (`submitted`, shown below)
that pushes data to the array.

It's working but with one problem: When I log
the data, it's not logging the last item pushed there.

This is the code:

```js
      submitted = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        let tmpData = [...this.state.data, this.state.txt]
        this.setState({
          data: tmpData
        })
        console.log(this.state.data)
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setState` is **asynchronous**.  Check out [the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous) on that.

If you want your state to log right after `setState` actually fires, `setState` takes a callback function which fires after `setState` actually updates the state:

```js
      submitted = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        let tmpData = [...this.state.data, this.state.txt]
        this.setState({
          data: tmpData
        }, () => console.log(this.state.data) )
      }
```